# sap 4 hana router logout not working properly

Tags: sap-cloud-platform

I have a sap trial account and I am developing a sap ui5 app with spring boot backend on cloud foundry. I also have an app router used for authentication/authorization and for access to my app. I have a simple page, index.html, which has a button that calls my spring backend ("/hello") and a logout button on it ("/my/logout").

All the links I give in this post are accessed only through approuter (/index.html, /hello and /debug are all relative paths to "https://approuter-p***trial.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com").

Here is the chain of events that I am doing and that has me puzzled:

1. After I login, I can call the spring backend by pushing my button and it returns 200 (OK).
2. After I logout by pressing the logout button (I am still on the same page, no redirect), I try calling the spring backend again by pressing the button and it returns 401 (OK). I can repeat this many times, it gives 401 (OK).
3. I try accessing the backend by calling the direct link from another tab in the same browser(https://approuter-p***trial.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/hello - it's the same link that gets called when I push my spring button) and I get a 200 - NOK!, I did not login in again...
4. I go back to the tab that had index.html opened and call the spring backend again by pressing my button - now it returns 200 also (NOK!)
5. I tried accessing the spring backend link from POSTMAN, no headers/cookies added - I get the same server response I do by calling it from index.html, by the spring button (same situations as above, sometimes 401, sometimes 200 if backend previously accessed directly in browser).

I also checked the token received via a "/debug" backend that prints it, and it seems that after I logout, any call to the spring backend directly from the browser (not from index.html or POSTMAN) receives a new JWT Token, which seems to be valid. The only difference I noticed was that the 200 responses come with the header "X-Frame-Options: DENY" and the 401 responses come with the header "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN". This was tested with Chrome and IE - both having the same behaviour.

Any ideas why this is happening? My xs-app.json (used by my-xsuaa service and conseqeuntly by approuter) looks like this:

```
{
  "welcomeFile": "index.html",
  "authenticationMethod" : "route",
  "routes": [{
    "source": "/",
    "target": "/",
    "destination": "app-destination-hello"
  }],
  "logout": {
     "logoutEndpoint": "/my/logout"
  },
  "destinations": {
     "app-destination-hello": {
       "logoutPath": "/myrest/logout",
       "logoutMethod": "GET"
     }
  }
}
```

Thanks!

I will attach some traces from the approuter, maybe it helps. These are the steps I took with the corresponding logs (did not skip any log entry between steps):

1. I press logout button from index.html:

   2018-08-31T15:37:50.63+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT #2.0#2018 08 31 12:37:50:632#+00:00#ERROR#/Handler#########-UTzTjYczINpXSxkJY_QXoWlfSF3dk0O######jlhzhep3#PLAIN##GET request to /my/logout completed with status 401 - Authentication required#
   2018-08-31T15:37:50.63+0300 [RTR/7] OUT approuter-p***trial.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com - [2018-08-31T12:37:50.632+0000] "GET /my/logout HTTP/1.1" 401 0 12 "https://approuter-p***trial.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36" "-" "10.0.137.79:61038" x_forwarded_for:"-" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"bb472547-cf0f-407d-6ccb-87d2dd42d4e7" response_time:0.002667543 app_id:"9ceaf8d0-7ee7-4fb2-84d0-05df07af7c01" app_index:"0" x_b3_traceid:"56fc90749079fa0f" x_b3_spanid:"56fc90749079fa0f" x_b3_parentspanid:"-"
   2018-08-31T15:37:50.63+0300 [RTR/7] OUT
2. I press the spring button from index.html (the endpoint name is now /hello2, but it's the same as before) and I receive a 401, which is OK:

   2018-08-31T15:37:57.57+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT #2.0#2018 08 31 12:37:57:575#+00:00#ERROR#/Handler#########utCeM-9IrqFW7oEOGkqMtIoUmwgTpZsv######jlhzhk1z#PLAIN##GET request to /hello2 completed with status 401 - Authentication required#
   2018-08-31T15:37:57.58+0300 [RTR/4] OUT approuter-p***trial.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com - [2018-08-31T12:37:57.583+0000] "GET /hello2 HTTP/1.1" 401 0 12 "https://approuter-p***trial.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36" "-" "10.0.137.79:61038" x_forwarded_for:"-" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"600551f2-7054-4d08-68aa-75d88f2584e2" response_time:0.003231487 app_id:"9ceaf8d0-7ee7-4fb2-84d0-05df07af7c01" app_index:"0" x_b3_traceid:"25c2df6333a965cf" x_b3_spanid:"25c2df6333a965cf" x_b3_parentspanid:"-"
   2018-08-31T15:37:57.58+0300 [RTR/4] OUT
3. I open the approuter/hello2 link from another browser tab and I receive a 200 (NOK): 
   2018-08-31T15:38:00.79+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT #2.0#2018 08 31 12:38:00:797#+00:00#INFO#/Auth/OAuth2#########pPyrBRKTJWcfwzc8yP8EExMmQbCfW992######jlhzhmjg#PLAIN##sending page with client-side redirect to https://p***trial.authentication.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=sb-firstapp3cris!t5664&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapprouter-p***trial.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com%2Flogin%2Fcallback#
   2018-08-31T15:38:00.80+0300 [RTR/5] OUT approuter-p***trial.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com - [2018-08-31T12:38:00.801+0000] "GET /hello2 HTTP/1.1" 200 0 483 "https://approuter-p***trial.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/hello2" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36" "-" "10.0.137.79:61038" x_forwarded_for:"-" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"5e18d1e8-f7e6-4b21-6f6a-2a7ea386c5cc" response_time:0.003697001 app_id:"9ceaf8d0-7ee7-4fb2-84d0-05df07af7c01" app_index:"0" x_b3_traceid:"89e2fc6581f0c47b" x_b3_spanid:"89e2fc6581f0c47b" x_b3_parentspanid:"-"
   2018-08-31T15:38:00.80+0300 [RTR/5] OUT
4. somehow a login is called automatically (I see a call in the index.html tab, but it is done when I press the logout button, also no reidrect page to ask me for username/password):
   2018-08-31T15:38:39.46+0300 [RTR/5] OUT approuter-p***trial.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com - [2018-08-31T12:38:39.158+0000] "GET /login/callback?code=UL6niGFX3T HTTP/1.1" 302 0 0 "https://p***trial.authentication.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36" "-" "10.0.137.79:61038" x_forwarded_for:"-" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"307eee0f-123f-46f6-7102-9ef370d66ab5" response_time:0.307257726 app_id:"9ceaf8d0-7ee7-4fb2-84d0-05df07af7c01" app_index:"0" x_b3_traceid:"a9a073166c04301f" x_b3_spanid:"a9a073166c04301f" x_b3_parentspanid:"-"
   2018-08-31T15:38:39.46+0300 [RTR/5] OUT
5. I press my spring button from approuter/index.html and now I receive 200 response here also:
   2018-08-31T15:38:39.70+0300 [RTR/1] OUT approuter-p***trial.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com - [2018-08-31T12:38:39.542+0000] "GET /hello2 HTTP/1.1" 200 0 85 "p***trial.authentication.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36" "-" "10.0.137.79:61038" x_forwarded_for:"-" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"b6400e34-87c0-47ea-4335-46d9c9348802" response_time:0.158048741 app_id:"9ceaf8d0-7ee7-4fb2-84d0-05df07af7c01" app_index:"0" x_b3_traceid:"eb6dde02e73d9c38" x_b3_spanid:"eb6dde02e73d9c38" x_b3_parentspanid:"-"
   2018-08-31T15:38:39.70+0300 [RTR/1] OUT
   2018-08-31T15:38:52.91+0300 [RTR/0] OUT approuter-p***trial.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com - [2018-08-31T12:38:52.897+0000] "GET /hello2 HTTP/1.1" 200 0 85 "approuter-p***trial.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36" "-" "10.0.137.79:61038" x_forwarded_for:"-" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"a29c59b9-ba64-4249-74ac-dbf9cf6b1255" response_time:0.014440749 app_id:"9ceaf8d0-7ee7-4fb2-84d0-05df07af7c01" app_index:"0" x_b3_traceid:"b16f601b3276909a" x_b3_spanid:"b16f601b3276909a" x_b3_parentspanid:"-"
   2018-08-31T15:38:52.91+0300 [RTR/0] OUT

Comment: I dont fully understand your setup and therefore ask myself the following questions which would probably clear some fog:

1. Is the index.html file served by the approuter or is this a local file? Because I wonder how you can press your test button after logout.
2. What does your magic button call: The backend directly or indirectly via the approuter because ...
3. In step 3 your URL suggest that you access your backend resource via the approuter which should lead to a new login which then would return a 200.

Comment: 4. You say your /debug servlet suggests you receive a new JWT after logout when accessing the backend directly? I don't understand this. When the AppRouter is not involved no new JWT should be issued anywhere.

Comment: Hello Phillip, I also edited my question a little bit. To answer your questions: 1. index.html is served by the approuter and so is every link I access (either from browser or postman). 2. My magic button also calls the backend through approuter and I can still press it because when I logout I do not redirect to another page, I am still on index.html. 3. I would expect a redirect to a login page when trying to access by backend directly from browser, but all it does is to somehow make the approuter re-generate a new JWT token that logs me in again automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Given your `xs-app.json` and the approuter URL I infer that the logout is located behind:

https://approuter-p***trial.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/my/logout.

Are you calling this endpoint to logout from the approuter? This should invalidate all your sessions as well as the JWT temporarily hold within the memory of the approuter.

Furthermore, when you access your Spring backend directly you should always receive 4xx error codes because no client actually ever has any JWT to access the spring-protected backend. In addition, the access to the Spring-based backend should be independent from any cookies or sessions because a JWT is used which by design is a stateless protocol. The only session cookie maintained is between your client and the approuter.

For more details on this, please refer to the [Extending SAP S/4HANA Book, Chapter 5](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/gxmedia.galileo-press.de/leseproben/4655/reading_sample_sappress_1715_ExtendingSAPS4HANA.pdf).

Comment: when I say I called my backend directly from the browser, it's through approuter but I meant that I put the link manually in a new tab (https://approuter-p***trial.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/hello). Indeed, if I access the backend from my app link, it will complain about a missing JWT. Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, is there a way to debug/investigate what the approuter does? Thanks

Comment: PS: I am indeed calling the endpoint above (https://approuter-p***trial.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/my/logout.) to logout.